# shell script for automated delivery, with git operations

Tags: bash, git, shell

I'm new in sh script and I try to do something. I want to automatize my delivery (last step is tag) and I don't really know how to do. I try something but I've got a problem

What I want :

- I have a file with repo url and folder where to pull. ex :

```
https://gitlab.toto.com/api_tata|api_tata
https://gitlab.toto.com/frontend_tata|frontend_tata
```

I want loop on each repo, pull on release branch, change version number, merge with main branch.

I try something like this for first step (clone a repo locally to execute merges and push)

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECTS_LIST="projects.txt"
DIRBASE="."

cd "$DIRBASE"

if [ ! -f "$PROJECTS_LIST" ]; then
   echo "The projects file ($PROJECTS_LIST) does not exist."
   read -p "Press Enter to exit..."
   exit 1
fi

while IFS=';' read -r REPO DIR || [[ -n "$REPO" ]]; do
   echo "Repo: $REPO"
   echo "DIR: $DIR"

   if [ -z "$REPO" ] || [ -z "$DIR" ]; then
       echo "Invalid format in the line: $REPO;$DIR"
       continue
   fi

   read -p "Press Enter to clone the repository..."

   # clone repo
   git clone "$REPO" "$DIR"

   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "Cloning successful."
   else
       echo "Cloning failed."
   fi

   read -p "Press Enter to continue..."
done < "$PROJECTS_LIST"
```

here the logs I put and the error :

```
Repo: https://gitlab.toto.com/api_tata
DIR: api_tata
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'api_tata?': Invalid argument
Cloning failed.
```

I don't know why I have this '?' character after api_tata ?

Please if you can help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) shows some errors. please may you address them?

Comment: run the command manually, change the git clone line to echo "get clone $REPO $DIR" .. see what is out put, then run that command manually ... then echo $?  to see the output

Comment: You didn't show how you set the variable `DIR`, so we can't say what is its context. You are just doing a `echo`, which is not a reliable way to peek into a variable. At least you could do something like `xxdump <<<$DIR` .

Comment: For the _main_ problem, run `bash -x yourscript` to log execution; you'll know (or we'll be able to know) more precisely what's going on given the contents of that log. Beyond that -- `foo; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then` is completely pointless. Just write `if foo; then`. Also, note that all-caps variables are in the space used for variables set by or meaningful to the shell and OS -- per https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use and won't conflict with behavior of POSIX-specified tools.

Comment: thanks all for the help ! I found something wrong on IFS=";", cause I replace at the end in my file by a pipe. I dont know how $DIR was good (or almost good) but now it's good, I can clone ! Thanks ! ANd thanks @CharlesDuffy for the bash -x, very useful for me !

Answer (score 0):

That likely means `DIR` ends with an invisible character. From my experience, it's usually a carriage return (`\r`).

Confirm it by adding this somewhere

```
echo "$DIR" | od -c
```

which dumps the invisibles (note the `\r` following api_tata)

```
0000000    a   p   i   _   t   a   t   a  \r  \n
0000012
```

Then correct `DIR` using either `tr` to remove specific character

```
git clone "$REPO" "$(tr -d '\r' <<< "$DIR")"
```

or remove all symbols except for accepted ones

```
git clone "$REPO" "${DIR//[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]}"
```

Comment: We have a canonical duplicate target for this class of problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : The CR (if it is one, and not some other invisible character) does not **necessarily** come from an incorrect line ending. We only know that it entered the stage when the variable `DIR` got its value. and since it is not explicitly set in this script, it must have happened in some parent process.

Comment: @user1934428 Indeed; the OP can figure that out with `set -x` logs, and thereafter will be equipped to ask a better question.

Comment: @user1934428, that said, the OP wouldn't need `|| [[ -n "$REPO" ]]` if they had a standard UNIX text file -- that's something that's necessary on Windows, where _both_ `\r` precedes `\n` _and_ the last line of the file has no terminator -- so we have significant circumstantial evidence.